# Converting ADSL Router in public wlan extender

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-bridge

### Problem

thanks a lot for your expert advise. I have a couple of old wireless routers and I would like to convert them as wireless extender for a Public Network.

### Description

The public network is broadcasting from not so far away, I have 60% of Wireless connection and I would like to improve it. Right now my download speed is around 1 MB/S.

The network is public, with sign in, the user needs to authenticate with his laptop with the browser and pay for usage. This are the details of the Wireless Network.

This are the details of the network:
Link speed 2 Mb/s

### Technical Details

The network I want to connect to:

Security None

IPv4 Address 10.178.225.199

IPv6 Address AC:B5:7D:F0:C9:59

Default Route 10.178.0.1

Default Route 10.178.0.1

My router is

Kraun
ADSL Router Model No.:KNL36

### Question

My question is if it is possible to use an old router as wireless repeater for a public network? The first issue is that I can not disable on the Public Network the **DHCP** (Dynamic Ip Address), as described from the following guides and I tried to set the connection, but It did not work.

This are the instruction that I should follow:

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/basics/wireless-basics/30338-how-to-convert-a-wireless-router-into-an-access-point

Additionally I would like to ask if it is possible, as described in the below Stackoverflow discussion to use different type of equipment to improve the wireless connection to the Public Network.
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29252/wlan-bridge-connected-over-wlan-to-the-internet

### Update

I tried the solution provided and followed the solution above.
This are the settings that I have done:

1. I tried both AP and Wireless brige, both manual and with scan. With scan the router find the Wireless Bridge I want to connect to, I am not sure if he loses the connection or can keep it.
2. In my router lan settings i do the following 
   ip 10.178.225.210
   primary dns 10.178.225.210
   Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
3. When i disable the dhcp my laptop need me to set up a static ip, so in my linux lan configuration i set manual ip address 
   ip 10.178.225.211
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 10.178.225.211
4. Then i can connect to the lan router settings, but I do not get connected to the public wifi. I could easily connect just with wireless, but with a limited connection of 1 mb/s

could you please give me some feedback?
Thanks a lot
Best Regards
Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: Is in the wlan-device, you want to use as repaeter, a function like "repeater mode" ? Perhaps this could be helpful too :              https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110218093225AAB47SC

Comment: @GiaRui Thanks a lot, I will try this out in a couple of days. Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

Kraun seems to be some italian-branded OEM routers.

Focusing straight on your question:

> My question is if it is possible to use an old router as wireless repeater for a public network? The first issue is that I can not disable on the Public Network the DHCP (Dynamic Ip Address), as described from the following guides and I tried to set the connection, but It did not work.

Yes, you can technically do that with any wireless router, but your mileage my vary based on the equipment you're using (or, to be more specific, the software that your device has).

In order to succesfully do that, you will need to be able do a few things:

1. Disable the DHCP Server on the device you're setting up as a repeater. This is needed so you don't have multiple DHCP servers on the same subnet that offer different settings to clients, randomly.
2. If your goal is to make them act as a **wireless repeater**, the modem/router will have to support this function - basically it needs the device to act both as a wireless client and as a wireless access point at the same time. Unfortunately not a lot of branded firmwares offer this option (because it doesn't make sense for the device's purpose, for home users). So in this case, your best bet is to figure out if your device has support for alternative firmware like OpenWRT or DD-WRT.
3. If you can wire the secondary device (this Kraun device) via ethernet (to one of it's LAN ports), then disabling the DHCP Server on it, while also making sure you change the primary IP address of the device (in case you have multiple on the network so they conflict) in order to be able to access it, should be more than sufficient.

Comment: Ok, the router has the AP and Wireless Extender functionality. Tonight I test again. I did not disable DHCP when activating the Wireless Extender. The Wireless Extender recognizes the Network I have to connect to (IPv4 Address 10.178.225.199). So, once I activate the Wireless Extender functionality I should connect via lan to the router, when I disable the DHCP I will have to configure the Static Ip address on my laptop side and on the router side? Or no Static Ip configuration is required? With my laptop I just connect to the router network or the original Public Network amplified?

Comment: @GiaRui Hello, I tested and I have the following problems, I will just edit my message with updated screenshots so you can see. Thanks a lot